# Google Assistant Training

Tags: android, voice-recognition, google-assistant-sdk, app-actions

Is there a way to teach google assistant my application name as it seems its voice recognition is only expecting English perfect words.

My app name is *Test* and google assistant is unable to recognize it. It detects it as "Test1" and sometimes "Test2".

I want to use Open_App_Feature later but this basic thing is also not working.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Related: https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/checklist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When developing an Action with a novel name, you may need to modify the pronunciation. This can be done through the Actions Console in the Invocation section. Below the display name there is an option to modify the pronunciation based on more regular words so that the name can be matched.

[image]